# Excel Change Row color at every change in value (non consecutive)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I want to change the color of the row at every change in a particular row value. The changed rows could be non-consecutive.

For example:

```
Customer Product Line  Product

1        Outdoor       Lawn Jarts
1        Indoor        Nerf Hoops
2        Outdoor       Ball Game
3        Indoor        Fort Builder
4        Indoor        Twist'Em
4        Indoor        Silly Silly
```

In this example, I would want customer 1 to be light blue; customer 2, white; customer 3 light blue; customer 4, white, repeating at every customer change.

[image: Color Change Excel]

I'd prefer to use a formula if possible.
Thanks.

EDIT: Customer numbers are non-consecutive numbers (1,15,49406, etc.)

Comment: I was about to warn you about this question possibly being downvoted since you didn't post any attempt of your own to solve this problem, but I see I stand corrected.

Comment: This sounds like a good time to use Conditional Formatting.  Do you want the coloring to be based on Customer number?  Or just every time the Customer number is different from the above?

Comment: Conditional Formatting doesn't highlight a change in customer when there is only one record, among other limitations with this approach.

Comment: I can't think of any excel "formula" that changes the interior color of a cell.

Comment: @MattCremeens: I'll use mod(row(),2) as a conditional format and change the cell color in the formatting area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in A2, highlight the Range A2:C7 (Or whatever range necessary) and then create a New Rule in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter this formula:

```
=MOD(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2)>0,1)),2)=1
```

If the customer numbers include text, you can use:

```
=MOD(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2,0),MATCH($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2,0))>0,1)),2)=1
```

Comment: What if the customer numbers are not consecutive integers?

Comment: Good point. I added an additional formula in my answer as an option.

Comment: This is it. I use mod(row(),2) a lot, so this will be a very useful piece of code for the future as well. Thanks.

Comment: Note: This doesn't seem to work when I changed my actual Customer number to text (cust # sometimes have a leading zero). I added another column as "general" and pasted in an extra customer number, which dropped the leading zero, did the formula, then hid the column.

Comment: I added a formula for text to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column like this:

[image]

In `D2` just put the literal string "Blue". Then in `D3` put the formula

```
=IF(A3<>A2,IF(D2="Blue","White","Blue"),D2)
```

And translate down.

On the entire sheet place a conditional format with the rule

```
=INDEX($D:$D,ROW())  = "Blue"
```

You can then hide column D if you want:

[image]

Comment: This slowed my spreadsheet to a crawl. Any way to speed it up?

Comment: @TravisHeeter This particular problem had a no-VBA requirement. Frankly, I have always found that somewhat annoying and would tend to prefer a VBA solution. If you have a problem which is similar to this problem but sufficiently different, you could always post another question.

Answer (score 0):

This formula works if you conditionally format based on column J, starting in cell J1.

```
=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($J$1:$J1,$J$1:$J1)))
```

Comment: Warning though: I tried applying this conditional format to 20K rows and it hung up my excel.  So apply carefully